# Where do the images in docker-compose.yml come from?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, hyperledger-fabric, docker-image

I'm not sure how exactly docker images work in the sense of, where do they come from. This is basically a three part question.

1. So for example when you type

```
docker run armhf/helloworld
```

and its not locally avaiable it pulls the image.

Now does it pull the image from the internet? Or does locally mean inside the container so it pulls from the pc for example.

Now in a Hyperledger docker-compose file like this (take from a pre existing example)

```
networks:
  basic:

services:
  ca.example.com:
    image: hyperledger/fabric-ca
    environment:
      - FABRIC_CA_HOME=/etc/hyperledger/fabric-ca-server
      - FABRIC_CA_SERVER_CA_NAME=ca.example.com
     ...
```

Do I need to download it from somewhere onto the pc so the container can find it or is this somehow able to pull it form the internet all by itself? Or does it depend on where its running, if its got access to the internet etc. ?

2. And what does it mean if theres a yaml file like this (Taken from another example for hyperledger on kubernetes)

```
image:
  tag: 1.2.0

persistence:
  accessMode: ReadWriteOnce
  size: 1Gi

peer:
  databaseType: CouchDB
  couchdbInstance: cdb-peer1
  mspID: AidTechMSP
...
```

This example doesnt even have a docker-compose file but is split in its different components. Does it not use an image?

3. (from the same example)

```
...
image: hyperledger/fabric-orderer:$IMAGE_TAG
...
```

(from the same example) Is this behind the $ something related to docker images?

Just a few things that confuse me because I'm only used to Windwos and I haven't found something that comprehensively answer these seemingly simple basic questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Images got pulled from internet according to the registry that your docker daemon points to:

```
#docker info|grep "^Registry:"
Registry: https://index.docker.io/v1/
```

For your second question I don't know where are you taking the example, if you could provide source it would be useful.

#### EDIT SECOND ANSWER AFTER COMMENT:

The yaml that you are referring on your second question looks like a kubernetes one, not docker if i'm not mistaken (don't know much about kubernetes).

For your third question, the variable refers to the version of the image, images have tags that could represent multiple containers with different versions, you could see this here for example:

https://hub.docker.com/_/centos?tab=tags

pulling the image following the appropriate tag you should be able to get for example:

### Centos 6:

```
 docker pull centos:6
```

### Centos 7:

```
 docker pull centos:7
```

### Centos 7.6.1810

```
docker pull centos:7.6.1810
```

Comment: [link](https://github.com/aidtechnology/lf-k8s-hlf-webinar)
This uses Kubernetes Helm to install a lot of things so it might rely on those. The files themselves are what I think you would get if you were to use Kompose on the docker-compose file. (Which transforms the file into readable files for Kubernetes as far as I know)

Comment: edited my answer about that configuration file on your second question